# team server foundation VS2010 setting up a workflow when task complete gets assigned to tester

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2010

I am very new to the whole team server foundation thing and I was hoping that you guys could point me in the right direction.

I have managed to successfully import a project from Microsoft Project 2010 into my VS 2010 tfs.  Everything so far works great.

I was just wondering if it is possible to have a task that was completed by a developer to send a notification and assign a testing task to the tester.

In other words:

1. The developer completed his / her task.
2. The developer updates the task in TFS to “Completed”
3. The task gets assigned to the tester for testing.
4. Notification goes to tester of new task he / she must test.

Is this possible or must I manually assign the developers completed task to the tester for testing?. Or is it possible to set TFS up to automatically do this?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the rule engine behind the work items. But how do you know the tester? I see two solutions.

1. Create a new field which has the tester in it. When the state is set to resolved the value of that field is copied to the AssignedTo.
2. Don't use the name of the tester but change the activity to Test when the state is changed to resolved.

In either way you can setup the work item alerts to get notified.

Resources:
[Define Work Item Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695793.aspx)
[Define and Customize Work Item Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243889.aspx)
[Set Personal or Team Alerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx)
[Configure Email Notifications and Specify the SMTP Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400808.aspx)